# Calculated Projected "End Date" for Event

Tags: forecasting, data-visualization, trend, moving-average

In reviewing average event duration (such as a service call), I notice that the most recent event average duration appears to be falling; appears to be a trend in event time reduction.
[image: Event Duration Over Time]

However, only events that have been completed/closed are displayed since the line is created by counting the total days between event creation and event completion.  The more difficult the event, the longer it takes to complete.  The trend is an accurate representation of the data today - but it will shift over time as more of the complex events with longer duration times are completed.

A review of events not yet completed shows the rise of incomplete events beginning in Q4 2015 and continuing to a crossover point in Q2 2018 where more events are open than are closed.

[image]

How can I project/forecast the event duration for the, as yet, incomplete events to ensure the viewer does not incorrectly assume the process is improving?  Average duration of all completed events prior to the Q4 2015 date is 202.9 days; Average duration of all completed events in the data set is 167 days.

Answer (score 0):

1. The average is not a good summary of event times. Use a Kaplan-Meier (KM) over the study periods instead. It summarizes the whole distribution of events.
2. Showing only completed events ensures more recent data does not display longer events (absolutely no context whatsoever, do events take longer than 3 months to do?). Methods for censored data should be applied if possible, again an argument for the KM.
3. I don't think your interpretation "[there] appears to be a trend in event time reduction.". is correct. More shorter things, fewer longer things, are also possible interpretations.

You can use non-parametric, semi-parametric, or parametric density estimation routines to estimate the distribution function of the event times over the study periods. If you can plot these, we can better advise forecasting and predicting.